# Configuration element containing a collection of child elements

Tags: c#, configuration, web-config, app-config

I want to have a custom section in my web.config like so:

```
<MyMainSection attributeForMainSection = "value foo">

    <add name = "foo" 
    type = "The.System.Type.Of.Foo, Assembly, Qualified Name Type Name" />

    <add name = "bar" 
    type = "The.System.Type.Of.Bar, Assembly, Qualified Name Type Name" />

</MyMainSection>
```

I have defined the following code:

```
using System.Configuration;

class MyMainSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    /*I've provided custom implemenation. 
      Not including it here for the sake of brevity. */ 
    [ConfigurationProperty("attributeForMainSection")]
    public string AttributeForMyMainSection { get; set; }

    [ConfigurationProperty("add")]
    public AddElement TheAddElement { get; set; }

    private class AddElement: ConfigurationElement
    {
        /* Implementation done */
    }

}
```

Should this property `TheAddElement` be `IEnumerable<AddElement>` or just `AddElement` if I want to allow multiple add elements?

Comment: You should really rename your question, it's pretty misleading based on what your actual question is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Neither, you would introduce a new [ConfigurationCollectionElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection.aspx) instead e.g.

**Section**

```
class MyMainSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("", IsRequired=true, IsDefaultCollection=true)]
    public AddElementCollection Instances 
    {
        get { return (AddElementCollection) this[""]; }
        set { this[""] = value; }
    }
}
```

**Collection**

```
public class AddElementCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection 
{
    protected override ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement() 
    {
        return new AddElement();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(ConfigurationElement element) {
        return ((AddElement) element).Name;
    }
}
```

**Element**

```
private class AddElement: ConfigurationElement
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsKey=true, IsRequired=true)]
    public string Name 
    {
        get { return (string) base["name"]; }
        set { base["name"] = value; 
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you, James. Just two more questions: (1) You haven't provided a key for the dictionary entry that stores the AddElementsCollection. Is that on purpose? Can I have a key of any name there or do I have to leave that blank? (2) You have named the property Instances. Is that mandatory or can I change that name?

Comment: Well actually that's *three* more questions :P To answer your questions on the key - The key you use here is whatever value you put in the `ConfigurationProperty` attribute, I left mines blank so I have to leave the indexer property blank. *"Can I have a key of any name there or do  I have to leave that blank?*" - You can use whatever key name you like, as long as it matches up with the `ConfigurationProperty` value. "*You have named the property Instances. Is that mandatory or can I change that name*" - Nope not mandatory, just for illustration purposes.

Answer (score 4):

> Use the [ConfigurationElementCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationelementcollection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to work with a collection of ConfigurationElement objects. Implement this class to add collections of custom ConfigurationElement elements to a ConfigurationSection:

```
// Define a custom section that contains a custom 
// UrlsCollection collection of custom UrlConfigElement elements. 
// This class shows how to use the ConfigurationCollectionAttribute. 
public class UrlsSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    // Declare the Urls collection property using the 
    // ConfigurationCollectionAttribute. 
    // This allows to build a nested section that contains 
    // a collection of elements.
    [ConfigurationProperty("urls", IsDefaultCollection = false)]
    [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(UrlsCollection),
        AddItemName = "add",
        ClearItemsName = "clear",
        RemoveItemName = "remove")]
    public UrlsCollection Urls
    {
        get
        {
            UrlsCollection urlsCollection =
                (UrlsCollection)base["urls"];
            return urlsCollection;
        }
    }

}

// Define the custom UrlsCollection that contains the  
// custom UrlsConfigElement elements. 
public class UrlsCollection : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
  // ...
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationcollectionattribute.aspx